# Should I care about form resubmission if it does not affect my registration setup?

Tags: php

Should I care about the form resubmission pop up even if it does not affect my user registration setup (script won't allow duplicate registration)? I can get around to avoid the form resubmission using sessions etc.. but just wondering if its worth the hassle?
Should I bother to try to avoid that popup or just validate the form without worrying about it?

I have tried and successfully removed the pop up using redirects and sessions but it does not seem good practice to me. Would I be better off by leaving the pop up and just validate the registration?

Comment: How do you differentiate between a form re submission and a duplicate submission where someone tries to use the same username. Do you handle the cases differently? If I know the webmaster is 'root' and have no password, will it fail to sign me up as root but log me in with any password?

Comment: Hello, No the script looks in the database for duplicate content. If the username exists in the database, the script will throw the user a error and prevent him from inserting in the database.

Comment: "Should I care about the form resubmission pop up" - what popup? It helps to frame question detail with the appropriate context.

Comment: So then, the original successful insert would then be overridden with a failed insert and the end result would seem like they weren't able to sign up?

Comment: The popup when it says to confirm form resubmission. It appears when you try to refresh the page on a form.

Comment: Dave, What i am saying is. My script validates all the user input, checks for duplication etc.. however when you refresh the page before submiting  the popup with Confirm form resubmit pops up. That does not affect me in any way. However should i bother to remove that for the user using another methods?

Comment: "The popup when it says to confirm form resubmission" - is this a browser message? If so, it means that you have accepted a POST operation, and then rendered screen output without first redirecting. This is not good practice if you are writing to the database/file (the exception is if you have an error/validation condition that prevents that writing). If any form that results in change is successful, you should redirect afterwards.

Comment: Hello, That is exactly what is happening as you described. It has error/validation condition. However i was wondering if i should take additional steps to remove the confirm form resubmission (browser message) via other methods. Is this too much hassle for what its worth?

Comment: Still no advice on what i should be doing?